# Jetty with filtering

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I've been struggling to get Jetty to run with maven filtering. The jetty:run uses the maven source directory so doesn't see the filtered file. jetty:run-exploded works fine but I can't update my webpages in realtime.

Surely there must be a way of using maven filtering and not having rerun the jetty task everytime I change a webpage?

(Is there a way to get eclipse to automatically copy the webpages to the target directory? I thought it would do this by default but it doesn't seem to work. I used to use an eclipse builder with a trigger and ant task but this seems a bit old fashioned.)

Answer (score 1):

I had almost same issue. I have solved my problem changing paths for jetty plugin. What I have done is simply

- Abstracting configuration over another profile. (Jetty in this example)
- Adding another resource director for filtering
- Changing the paths for jetty plugin to configure

  ```
  <profile>
   <id>jetty</id>
   <build>
      <resources>
         <resource>
            <directory>../../conf/jetty</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
         </resource>
      </resources>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
            ..
            <configuration>
               <jettyConfig>${project.build.outputDirectory}/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
               <webAppConfig>
                  <contextPath>/${jettyContextName}</contextPath>
                  ..
                  <jettyEnvXml>${project.build.outputDirectory}/jetty-env-${jetty-env}.xml</jettyEnvXml>
               </webAppConfig>
               <stopKey/>
               <stopPort/>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
  ```

If you share your configuration we can assist for further modifications. But basically what you want to do is not easy task and dangerous because of changing the files **inplace**.

There could be another suggestion too. Despite of not recommending this way, You might run war:inplace before jetty:run like this.

```
    mvn war:inplace jetty:run
```

However I havent tried this solution and I suggest you to stay away from this way.